# Woocommerce replace a product options label depending on language

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to change the text string depending on the language with some code in functions.php
"Groesse" to "Größe" in German
"Groesse" to "Size" in English

Usually I use this code in functions.php, but when I want to access the product options label, this does not work.

```
function replace_content($content)
{
if (get_locale() == 'en') { 
    $content = str_replace('Groesse', 'Size', $content);}
    else {
    $content = str_replace('Groesse', 'Größe', $content);}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

How to access the label for product options in woocommerce products?

Answer (score 0):

The woocommerce filter for product attribute labels is "woocommerce_attribute_label". This can be used to rename product attribute labels. eg as part of a workaround when WPML does not correctly translate umlauts in product attributes (and the corresponding label)

````
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label' , 'custom_attribute_label', 10000 , 3 );

function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ) {
    switch( $label ){
        case 'Groesse': $label = 'Gr&ouml;&szlig;e'; break;
        case 'size': $label = 'Size'; break;
    }
    return ( $label );
}
```
````